# explanation of haskell function

Tags: function, haskell

The code I am looking at contains this top level function:

```
starman :: String -> Int -> IO ()
starman word n = turn word ['-' | x <- word] n
```

I can see that this is a function that takes 2 arguments and then calls the turn function that looks like this:

```
turn :: String -> String -> Int -> IO ()
turn word display n =
  do if n==0
       then putStrLn "You lose"
       else if word==display
              then putStrLn "You win!"
              else mkguess word display n
```

What I don't understand is what this means:

```
word ['-' | x <- word]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full line is:

```
starman word n = turn word ['-' | x <- word] n
```

`turn` is called with three parameters:

```
word
['-' | x <- word]
n
```

The middle one is the one you're having trouble with. It can be read as: "a hyphen for each character in word."

So `['-' | x <- "hello"]` is `"-----"`.

This construct is known as [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension).

**EDIT**

The list comprehension does the same thing as this, which is perhaps clearer in intent?

```
replicate (length word) '-'
```

Comment: The `replicate` version doesn't work with infinite strings.

Comment: True. I imagine that's not a possibility here.

Comment: @melpomene No, but neither does `==` which is used in the turn function. Infinite lists aren't really a concern here.

Comment: A more accurate alternative would be `map (\_ -> '-') word` or, equivalently, `map (const '-') word`.

Answer (score 2):

`word` is the first argument to the `turn` function.

`['-' | x <- word]` is the second argument and it's a list containing one `'-'` for each letter `x` in `word`. The fact that we give each letter the name `x` accomplishes nothing though, as we never refer to it, so we might as well write `['-' | _ <- word]`.

This syntax is known as a list comprehension and is meant to look similar to set notation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the following expression

```
turn word ['-' | x <- word] n
```

there a function (`turn`) call, with three arguments: `word`, `['-' | x <- word]`, and `n`. So `['-' | x <- word]` is independent of `word`.

Now, what is the meaning of `['-' | x <- word]`? This is a list comprehension, so it's an expression that constructs a list. In order to understand this, you have to remember that strings in haskell are just lists of characters. So `word` is a list. The `x <- word` means: take each element of the list `word`, call it that element `x` and then for each such element, evaluate the expression `'-'` and collect all those values into a list. In this case, the expression `'-'` does not reference `x`, so it will always evaluate to `'-'`. So in other words, we are taking the list of characters `word` and creating a list where each element-character is replaces by `'-'`.

Here are some equivalent ways to do the same thing:

```
['-' | _ <- word]              -- use the anonymous variable, we don't need the element
map (\_ -> '-') word
map (const '-') word
'-' <$ word                    -- my favorite one!
replicate (length word) '-'    -- the least preferrable way
```